# Update HTML content every minute with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, updating

I am writing a script to update my html content, which I have set to update once each day, but now need to change it to update every minute. Here is what I have come up with so far, please ignore the fact that it is not all complete.

```
//get date

Date.prototype.getDOY = function() {
    var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
    return Math.ceil((this - onejan) / 86400000);
} 

// make new date
var today = new Date();
var DOY = today.getDOY(); 

var HL=new Array();

//Configure the following array to hold the 365 HLs for each day of the year

HL[1]='HL 1 goes here';
HL[2]='HL 2 goes here';
HL[3]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[4]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[5]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[6]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[7]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[8]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[9]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[10]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[11]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[12]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[13]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[14]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[15]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[16]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[17]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[18]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[19]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[20]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[21]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[22]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[23]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[24]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[25]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[26]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[27]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[28]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[29]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[30]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[31]='HL 3 goes here';
HL[32]='HL 3 goes here';

//... for the sake of time, skip to last day of year:

HL[365]='HL 3 goes here';

document.write(HL[DOY]);
```

Comment: `setInterval(function(){  //update stuff here }, 60000)`??

Comment: This seems like an [x y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Whatever you're doing with this array, there is certainly a better way to do it. If you can tell us what your end goal is, in more detail, we can suggest a more appropriate aproach

Comment: My end goal is to have a paragraph contain different content (for which i will specify) every time the user will refresh the page, it needs to have thousands of updates with different info

Comment: It basically needs to have just text updates into certain parts, for which i will specify in the script, an example is found at the link: http://aswanson.net/JeffWork/4-28.html